# Javascript dynamically function calls in for loop

Tags: javascript, function, call, dynamically-generated

Suppose you want to do something like this in Javascript:

```
const items = {identifier1, identifier2, identifier3 ...}

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    this.addMyMethod(items[i], items[i]);
}
```

...and then anywhere else in the script, you could do something like this:

```
var result1 = this.MyMethod.identifier1.result;
var result2 = this.MyMethod.identifier2.result;
var result3 = this.MyMethod.identifier3.result;
...
console.log(result1, result2, result3, ...);
```

This works properly, but I want to do it dynamically; something like this:

```
method.allMyMethods = function() {

    var results = [];

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        results.push[items[i]] = this.MyMethod.items[i].result;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

But using the code above, when I try this:

```
this.MyMethod.items[i].result;
```

...Javascript reports an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items[0]' of undefined
```

I hope you understand what I a trying to do (BTW, I'm hoping to avoid using use `eval`).

Maybe someone can explain my mistake?

Much thanks

Comment: Some re-wording and indentation cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a lookup via indexer:

```
this.MyMethod[items[i]].result;
```

Comment: Hi, plz look at my second answer. Maybe you can resolve it.